# Plotting discontinuous line segments in Python

Tags: plot, line, segment

Firstly, I am very, very new to Python. I am trying to come close to a product I make in Excel charts by plotting X and Y. I want to be able to export the data from Excel to a text file and the read into Python to produce the chart. In Excel I have the line segments, defined by X and Y values, separated by empty cells in columns and the other segments in other columns. For right now I am just exporting a single column with the objective of having more columns. So if the image shows up in this post you will see that the different line segments are all connected by straight lines, sort of like Etch-a-Sketch. I got errors when I had blank lines in the text file where I had empty cells in the Excel data. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

￼[Attempted chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfbNi.png)